# How to catch event when somebody move finger horizontally over ScrollView?

Tags: android, android-widget

I have ScroolView over whole screen and vertical scroll works fine. How to catch event when somebody move finger horizontally over ScrollView ? I need to do some math when user move finger horizontally and vertically to stay as it is .

Answer (score 0):

You can do so by using a GestureDetector class in the ScrollView's setOnTouchListner() method.

The GestureDetector  will give you callback methods for different gestures. You can implement the onFling method to make it recognize left or right flick.

This [link](http://www.androidsnippets.com/gesturedetector-and-gesturedetectorongesturelistener) might be helpful.

I hope this will help...